# XAML Path Syntax

Tags: xaml

I'm trying to create what I believe is a basic shape using XAML. Essentially, I need to create something that looks like the following:

```
______________^______________
|                            |
| Some static text will be   |
| placed here in the bubble  |
|____________________________|
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas">
  <Path Stroke="#2D2D2D" Fill="#2D2D2D"></Path>
  <TextBlock Text="Some static text will be placed here in the bubble." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Canvas>
```

Obviously, the `Data` portion of the `Path` element is missing. However, I can't figure out that syntax. It seems so weird. All I want is a rectangle that has a triangle in the middle of the top border. This makes it looks like a chat bubble. Can someone explain how I can do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you found and read the [path markup syntax guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)? A few `H` (horizontal lines) and `V` (vertical lines) segments and one or two `L` (lines to an arbitrary point) segments should do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of you learning something, as opposed to just being given a solution. This is along the lines of what you're looking for;

```
<Path Data="M125.11371,0.5 L141.0695,20.500002 L249.5,20.500002 L249.5,
      119.5 L0.5,119.5 L0.5,20.500002 L108.9748,20.500002 z" 
      Fill="#FF2D2D2D" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2D2D2D" 
      UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="250" Height="100"/>
```

They way I did this was in Expression Blend, I first drew a `Rectangle` and then using the Pen tool I drew a Triangle and positioned in the top center of the previous `Rectangle`

I then selected both objects and from the top menu selected **Object -> Combine -> Unite** which produced this final result.

If you're better with a more Vector oriented program like Adobe Illustrator, there's a [XAML Exporter](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) by Mike Swanson that comes in handy quite often, especially for more complicated XAML designs than this.

Your design is one of the  easiest you could likely come up with so you can't wonder why nobody will generally want to just answer it blatantly. However I was in your situation before so it's provided, but hopefully something was also learned you can apply when this type of situation pops up again.

Hope this helps and best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I was looking for. I'd rather learn how to do it in the tool so I can do it in the future. Great response.

Answer (score 1):

[You can read about paths here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)

There are two ways to create a path:

1. Using figures (Lines, Polylines, ...)
2. Using the [Mini language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)

Comment: The MSDN documentation you linked to doesn't exist any more ("We're sorry—the topic that you requested is no longer available. Use the search box to find related information."). Instead, the [.NET 4.0 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the topic can be used.

Comment: When you see "doesn't exist anymore" on MSDN check the "Previous Versions" dropdown.