# UWP/XAML Custom border for a shape

Tags: xaml, uwp, stroke

I need to create a rectangle that has a cloud-like border.  Do I need to create a custom Stroke or should I be looking at creating something else?

Comment: Define "cloud-like".

Comment: uniform sine-wave-like pattern with only peaks, no troughs; with a 90 degree rotation moving clock-wise around the edge of a typical rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any border properties can provide you with a more advanced shape than rounded edges by using CornerRadius. By defining a GradientBrush inside Border.BorderBrush you could get some advanced coloring, but i think you should look at drawing a path if you want the border to look like a cloud. I found this code for a custom shape [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501732/xaml-path-syntax). I'm no expert at the path data, so I can't help you draw the shape but pretty sure you will be able to create a cloud.

```
<Path Data="M125.11371,0.5 L141.0695,20.500002 L249.5,20.500002 L249.5,
119.5 L0.5,119.5 L0.5,20.500002 L108.9748,20.500002 z" 
Fill="#FF2D2D2D" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2D2D2D" 
UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="250" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think you are correct.  My further research points to me needing to create paths for each rectangle edge. I will most likely be creating a customized Rectangle Shape that adds 4 paths.